# How to get System Login and logoff time in ASP.net MVC4

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Am new to ASP.net MVC4
I want to do program which can record the system login time and system logoff time along with IP address.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: What's the question ? Did you try anything ? What exactly are you facing troubles with ?

Comment: Where do you want to store these info? DB? Session?

Answer (score 1):

To record Client IP Address use

```
HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress //In Controller

or 

HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress// In Classes
```

To record Login and Logout time.

Create a custom action filter class and record the datetime as given below.

---

```
[CustomFilter(CurrentAction="Login")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
  ...
}

[CustomFilter(CurrentAction="Logout")]
public ActionResult Logout()
{
  ...
}
```

---

```
public class CustomFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    String CurrentAction {get; set;}

    void IActionFilter.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)    
    {
        // TODO: Add your action filter's tasks here

      MyDBEntities storeDB = new MyDBEntities ();

      if(CurrentAction.Equals("Login"))
      {
           LoginDetail log = new LoginDetail ()
           {
              LoginTime= DateTime.Now,
              IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
           };
           storeDB.LoginDetails.Add(log);
      }
      else if(CurrentAction.Equals("Logout"))
      {
          LoginDetail log = new LoginDetail ()
          {
            LogoutTime= DateTime.Now,
            IP = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.UserHostAddress
          };
          storeDB.LoginDetails.Add(log);
      }

      storeDB.SaveChanges(); 
      this.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for all your responds...but i have mentioned it as "system login time" not the asp application login or logout time..i would like to create an application which need to run in system's start up or in background and when the the user switch on the system and logging in the application should get the time of login and same in logout..

Answer (score 0):

A windows service or running your application at autostart would solve this.

Please take care of storing data, user session ending to safe handle storing it when the system gets shutdowned.

Please refer to the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx).

[Create a windows service:](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C)

Or

[Add your application to autostart](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-add-a-program-to-startup/91d18255-659e-4796-87f6-5e6c814c7d50%5B%5E%5D)